# What is default order for Windows Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, azure, azure-storage

When I check Windows Azure Storage table content by Visual Studio in Server Explorer I'm impressed that date are in chaotic order.

What is default order for Windows Azure Storage? I need info about order and direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is sorted alphabetically by "PartitionKey" first and then by "Rowkey" in a "Partition".

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx

From this link:

> Query results are sorted by PartitionKey, then by RowKey. Ordering
>   results in any other way is not currently supported.

Comment: @'Gaurav Mantri' Thanks for your quick answer. What about TimeStamp is it also used in default sorting?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Timestamp isn't used for default sorting.